# LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); Doesn't seem to work. Please check my codes

Tags: android, facebook

I was trying to make a logout button for my app and It doesn't seem to work. Could you please check my code? Thank you! I was using FB Sdk 4.0

```
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    logout= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logout);
```

Here's my Logout onclick

```
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            hideall();
            reset();
        }
    });
```

Here's my FB Share udf

```
    public void sharefbsure()
{
    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

    manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

    manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new  FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
   {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            publishImage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
           System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to put log inside callback methods to check whether they are called or not.

Comment: Doesn't say anything. Please help

Comment: @codesofdave Did you find a solution  ?  I am on the same situation

Comment: I am having the same issue.